# Using Dynamic Data Masking in SQL Server set Custom String

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-data-masking

I need to mask the data in the following table.
[image]

For example, I need to mask the first_name of the user Roberto to something like `NAME<<userID>>`, So the end result should look like `NAME1`

Is this possible in SQL Server?

My SQL Server details below.

[image]

I have tried these methods from the documentation but still no luck
[from documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15#defining-a-dynamic-data-mask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to data in some other column so if that 1 should come from the MemberId column, then you are out of luck. What you have to play with are the prefix and suffix, and those need to be from the same column as the masking is defined on.